# How to get exact value of a field from database?

Tags: 7, nodes

I want to get value of a field, but I need the value that is saved in database, not the value that may be changed by `hook_node_load`. Is there a way to do this?

If there is no function for this purpose, which query should I use to get the field value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure there's an API function to get this directly; the field functions (like  [`field_get_items()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/function/field_get_items/7)) seem to rely on a loaded entity object, which in the case of a node would have gone through the whole loading process.

If you want to get the value directly you'll find the data in the `field_data_field_*` tables. A query like the following would get the data for a node of type 'article', assuming a text field called 'field_my_field' with a column name of 'value'. It also assumes the field is not multiple; if it is you'll need to remove the last line of the query and loop through `$val` instead:

```
$val = db_select('field_data_field_my_field', 'f')
  ->fields('f', array('field_my_field_value'))
  ->condition('entity_type', 'node')
  ->condition('bundle', 'article')
  ->condition('entity_id', $node->nid)
  ->execute()
  ->fetchField();
```

If you've got node revisions turned on for the content type in question you'll probably need to alter this to query the `field_revision_field_my_field` table instead, and use the node revision id (`vid`) instead.

Answer (score 2):

There are quite a few more places that a field or entity could be changed, other than just `hook_node_load()`.

You might poke through the [`field_attach_load()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.attach.inc/function/field_attach_load/7) function for some insight into which hook you want to support to catch fields before they're fully loaded.

Everywhere you see a `module_implements()` or any function call with `_invoke_` in it, that's the field system calling a hook. There are a bunch. :-)

If you drill down, like maybe through `_field_invoke_get_instances()` and then `field_read_instances()`, you end up seeing:

[`hook_field_read_instance()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.api.php/function/hook_field_read_instance/7)

Whether you want to implement this depends on why you need the info and what you plan to do with it.